# Problems with animation on a png image

Tags: java, swing, animation

Hello all So I'm making progress on my animation program but I'm running into a problem where my alien.png isn't showing up in the jframe. I have the alien.png in the same folder as this animation demo.java so I'm not sure why its not finding the alien.png. Any help would be appreciated

```
package animationdemo;


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimationDemo extends JFrame  {
    Image alien;
    public AnimationDemo() {

    alien = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("alien.png");
    MovingMessagePanel messagePannel = new MovingMessagePanel();
    messagePannel.alien = this.alien;
        Timer timer = new Timer(50, messagePannel);
    timer.start();
    this.add(messagePannel);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnimationDemo frame = new AnimationDemo();
    frame.setTitle("Project 10");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}

class MovingMessagePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  public int xCoordinate = 20;
  public int yCoordinate = 20;
  public int xDir=5;  
  public int yDir=5;
  public Image alien;

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (xCoordinate > getWidth()) xDir*=-1;
    if (yCoordinate > getHeight()) yDir*=-1;
    if (xCoordinate <0) xDir*=-1;
    if (yCoordinate <0) yDir*=-1;
    xCoordinate += xDir;
    yCoordinate += yDir;
    g.drawImage(alien,xCoordinate,yCoordinate,this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the code lines:

```
package animationdemo; // this one!

import java.awt.Graphics;
// ..

public class AnimationDemo extends JFrame  {
    Image alien;
    public AnimationDemo() {

    alien = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("alien.png"); // & this one!
```

That last line is effectively trying to load a `File` from the 'current directory'.

But the image probably won't be accessible as a `File` any longer.  Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Note given the first highlit line, the best path for finding the resource would presumably be:

```
..getResource("/animationdemo/alien.png")
```

Note also that the `getResource` method is case sensitive, so ..

```
..getResource("/animationdemo/alien.PNG")
```

.. won't find the lower case version, nor vice-versa.

---

As an aside, I did a check of my 'missing image' theory by making this small change to the source above:

```
    alien = new BufferedImage(40, 40, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("alien.png");
```

Given I saw an animated black square, it supports the major problem is that the image is not being found. The code still has a few other aspects that should be tweaked, but it is basically going in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense I'm just not sure how to declare the alien variable I was trying this but its telling me it can't find URL URL alien = this.getClass().getResource("/animationdemo/alien.png");

Comment: Do you use an IDE? If so, which one? Is the image stored in the same place as the `AnimationDemo.java` source file? (That is the wrong place, if using an IDE.)